# What number is Einsfünfundvierzig?

Tags: meaning, numbers

Two characters in a book were talking about the price of a commodity and the price was Einsfünfundvierzig. I am not sure if it is 45 or 145.
Tanks

Answer (score 13):

It's 1 Euro and 45 cents – or whatever denominations are in use in the story. The currency word can be left out in speech when the number is still clear unambiguously.

- 199,95 € → einhundertneunundneunzig (Euro) fünfundneunzig
- 1,45 € → eins fünfundvierzig / ein Euro fünfundvierzig
- 20,75 € → zwanzig (Euro) fünfundsiebzig

You have to add the currency word for prices like 200,38 as "zweihundert achtundreißig" would be indistinguishable from "zweihundertachtundreißig" (238). Thus:

- 200,38 € → zweihundert Euro achtunddreißig
- 238,00 € → zweihundertachtunddreißig Euro

Comment: American English has similar shortenings, for example "nine ninety nine" for $9.99 . I'm guessing the British do something like that too, at least post-decimalisation. I suppose it's all mashed into one word in German because that's the normal way to write numbers.

Comment: @RDBury No, it's not mashed into one word. The cents are separated from the main unit, just the way it's written in this answer.

Comment: @idmean I'd say the non-separated form is more common, but it's hard to tell because these are rarely ever written down as words. Einsfuffzig would normally just be written as 1,50.

Comment: @HalvarF Der Duden schreibt es jedenfalls auseinander (z. B. https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Zahlen). Zusammengeschrieben finde ich persönlich auch deutlich weniger lesbar...

Comment: That it can only be currency is wrong: it could equally be length/height ("Wie groß bist Du?" "Eins fünfzig.") or many other units where values with (two decimal) fractions are common.

Comment: @bakunin which other unit other  than currencies and lengths in metres with an accuracy in centimetres does it apply to? I cannot come up with any other quantity I'd use it on. Using it for weight, volumes, velocities or similar sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Lengths of time, though heavily dependent on context. "Wie lange soll das in die Mikrowelle? - Eins dreißig." = 1 Minute 30 Sekunden. "Welche Zeit ist er beim Marathon gelaufen? - Zwei dreizehn." = 2 Stunden 13 Minuten. Generally when the smaller unit has at most two digits, which is the reason why it isn't used for weights or volumes, where the smaller unit is a thousandth of the bigger one.